# Initializing Fabric on multiple targets

Tags: twitter-fabric

I have a module layer (embeds a framework) within my application to serve as a generic logging service to several services like Fabric, Mixpanel etc.

This module has a target dependency with the main app target.

I am initializing Fabric in the main app target's AppDelegate and later making calls to the Module layer for sending custom logs of this sort:

```
`CLSLogv("%@", getVaList("Some Log"))`
```

This however does not work unless I explicitly initialize Fabric in the Module layer

```
`Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self()])`
```

(The same way I've done it in the AppDelegate.)

I have NOT added a run script phase for Fabric in the Module target.

My question is, is this needed really since the module is a target dependency to the main app target and it already initializes Fabric in its app delegate?

If it is needed, is this going to cause any issues?